# Delete lines from a file that are between two lines indicated

Tags: php, symfony

I need to delete the lines that are between #bundle and #endbundle, ¿how can i do that?

```
new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
new CreatorBundle\CreatorBundle(),

#bundle
new CommerceBundle\CommerceBundle(),
#endbundle

new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
```

Comment: You should specify what have you tried so far or what seems to be the stopping point in your effort. Reading a text file? Determining which lines should be omitted? Writing to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Php fopen to open a file. 
Php file to read a file.
Php preg_match to find some text.